# How to use 2 lattice to deform 2 spheres on impact

Tags: lattice

I put a lattice around my sphere per basic deform set up:

[image]

Instead of modifying the sphere from the inside, I want the inverse effect.  I want the sphere to squash like a ball when it interactions with it.

[image: before I parent]

[image]

This works.  Now here is the advance set up where I'm stuck.  I want 2 balls that are part of the same object to interact with each other, using the lattice modifier, they would squash equally from both sides.

[image]

I had to modify this in edit mode because if I can get a photo, than I wouldn't need to ask this question :)

I got stuck as soon as I tried to bind the 2 balls into a lattice.  They deform immediately which is not what I want.

[image]

[image: After I parent]

I'm assuming this can probably be done easily if I make the balls 2 separate objects.  But that's the challenge here - I don't want to.  Is what I'm asking for possible with a single object?

Edit: They will be animated to squash with bones.

Comment: More lattice divisions maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need to keep your 2 balls within one object, but you could try it with *Lattice* or with *Mesh Deform* or even with shapekeys.

If you want to do it with *Lattice*, scale the lattice it in *Object* mode (not *Edit* mode) so that it contains your 2 ball object, in the *Properties* panel > *Object Data > Lattice*, give it enough *Resolution* (i.e. subdivisions):

[image]

Now create a basic shapekey, then another one:

[image]

In *Edit* mode, squish your lattice the way you want:

[image]

Back to *Object* mode, keyframe the shapekey value to animate:

[image]

Here is what it could give:

[image]

Comment: Let's say I want to make breast. :)

Comment: have you looked into shapekeys? Maybe it will make it easier

Comment: Yes, I'm good with shape keys. It just want  better way to uniformly deform a mesh before applying it a a shape key.  Say i have 2 breast obviously, it's going to be in the same mesh.  But even in a static position, they'll be squashed together. I try to use lattice deformer to do this.  Now I'm having issues because Lattice deforms whole mesh.  I just want the area that is inside the lattice to deform.

Comment: You can assign the breasts to an vertex group and select this group in the Lattice modifier so that only these vertices will be affected, you can do the same with a Mesh Deform modifier

Comment: Do you know if there is a better modifier for this?  I think there is a mesh deformer that does something similar?  Am I looking at this problem with the wrong modifier?

Comment: Yes you can try with the Mesh Deform modifier, again select the vertex group in the modifier. But as I said, in my opinion shapekeys only would be even simpler

Comment: I'm not sure what the other deformers do.  I plan to use shape keys to do this but I need uniform deformity first I can control.  I think the cast modifier might be more helpful here.  maybe..  How would you approach this problem?

Comment: yes Lattice seems ok actually, look at my edit (last animated gif)

Comment: What is that block doing there in the back? o_O

Comment: it's the woman's body   ^^